# c function to store a complete card deck into a dynamically linked array

Tags: c, arrays, linked-list

I want to make a function that stores a complete card deck like this:

- AS 2S 3S 4S 5S 6S 7S 8S 9S TS JS QS KS...

and so on on a dynamically linked list, where each node has only one card.
This is what I have tried, but It does't work.
Please note that the deck is stored in a .txt file.

```
void make_list(deck[52][3])
    {
        typedef struct cards
            {
                char card[3];
                struct cards *next;
            } cards_t;

        int j;

        cards_t *head = NULL; //initialization
        head = (cards_t*) malloc (sizeof(cards_t));

        for (j=0; j<52; j++)
            {
                head-> card[3] = deck[j][3];
                head->(next + j) = (cards_t*) malloc(sizeof(cards_t)); 
            }
```

I'm pretty much a beginner so any detailed explanations of my mistakes or resolutions would be very much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see a few high level problems with the code.

1. When you have a double char pointer (deck), you would access a single character as `deck[x][y]` but if you wanted the entire `AS` then you would just need `deck[x]`.
2. Your `for` loop is changing the value of head every time, it isn't making a list. At the end of that for loop, the only changed values will be head and next. This will also cause plenty of memory leaks because you malloc a new `struct cards` but then immediately lose the address to it in the next iteration.
3. Your access of `head->card[3] = deck[j][3]` is invalid. The `[3]` attached to card is invalid and should just be `head->card = deck[j]`.
4. A linked list doesn't quite work like you tried in (next + j). That would be better suited for an array. For a list, you have to navigate through the list to add a node (or possibly have a pointer to the end of the list).
5. Your method return is void, but since you define your entire list in the method, it should probably return the head of the node so all of the data is available from outside the method. It is also important to note that if the `deck` variable goes out of scope, then the list will point to garbage data because it can get overwritten in memory. If you wanted to avoid this, you would need to either ensure deck doesn't go out of scope or do a `memcpy` or `strcpy` for each card.

If you want to initialize a linked list of cards it would be more like

```c
typedef struct cards //Should be done outside of function
{
  char card[3]; //2 characters + '\0'
  struct cards * next;
} cards_t;

cards_t * make_list(char ** deck) //Assuming deck is double character array as you showed it
{
   //Initialize values
   int j = 0;
   cards_t *head = malloc (sizeof(cards_t)); //Note it isn't required to cast from malloc

   //Iterate over the deck and append to the linked list
   //here, we will start our variable at the head of the list. We will repeat 
   //this iteration 53 times and after each iteration, 
   //the variable will move onto the next node of the linked list.
   for (cards_t * iterator = head; j<52; iterator = iterator->next, j++)
   {
      iterator->card = deck[j]; //This will store the 3 card character name
      iterator->next = malloc(sizeof(cards_t)); 
   }//for

   return head;
}//make_list
```